# Exception while simulating the effect of invoking 'upvote'. TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, coffeescript, meteor

trying to add “**upvoting**" to specific courses for [Crowducate.me](http://crowducate.me/).

[image]

As you see from the image, the method is properly called. However, I think the update method (mongo) is not understood. Here’s my personal source code with [all commits on Github.](https://github.com/Rahbaran/crowducate.me)

My courses.coffee (mongo collection) // btw: can't format proper indentation here:

```
class @Course extends Minimongoid
@_collection: new Meteor.Collection('courses') 
...
Meteor.methods({
  createCourse: ->
    userId = Meteor.userId()
    throw new Meteor.Error 403, 'Please login to create a course' unless userId
    title = 'New Course'
    course = Course.create {
    owner: userId, courseTitle: title, published: 0, upvoters: [], votes: 0, slug: slugify(title)
  }
  return course._id

  upvote: (courseId) ->
    course = Course.first({_id: courseId})
    console.log course

  #userId = Meteor.user()
    Course.update {
      _id: courseId,
      # upvoters: {$ne: user._id}
      # }, {
      # $addToSet: {upvoters: user._id}
      $inc: {votes: 1}
    }
```

And my html

```
<template name="courseListItem">
  <div class="course-list-item">
    <a href="{{#if isMyCoursesPath}}{{pathFor 'courseUpdate'}}{{else}}{{pathFor 'courseShow'}}{{/if}}">
      <div class="course-img">
        {{#if courseOwner}}
        <div class="owner-options">
          <a href="{{pathFor 'courseUpdate'}}" class="btn btn-default" title="Edit Course"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
          <button class="btn btn-danger delete" title="Delete Course"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
        </div>
        {{/if}}
        <img class="img-resonsive" src="{{courseThumb}}">
      </div>
      <div class="well relative">
        <div class="course"><h4>{{maxChars courseTitle 40}} by {{owner}}</h4></div>
        <p class="course-list-item-preview-text">{{maxChars getText 65}}</p>
        <p class="course-list-item-preview-text-votes"><a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="upvote fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></a> <strong>{{votes}}</strong> Votes</p>
        <!-- <p class="course-list-item-preview-text">12 Votes</p> -->
        <div class="bottom">
          <p><i class="fa fa-tags" title="Tags"></i> {{maxChars getKeywords 28}}</p>
          <p><i class="fa fa-group" title="Age Group"></i> {{age}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</template>
```

My helper:

```
'click .upvote': (evt) ->
    Etc.prevent(evt)
    Meteor.call 'upvote', this._id
```

Maybe this is something specific reg. to Coffeecode or MinimongoId? If you want to run this locally, use mrt install and don’t update to the packages or meteor. Plus, you test the up voting, you need to quickly create a course (under section “teach”).

Best,
Amir
P.S.: Just to let you know: I’m extending another person’s code and don’t have a lot of experience with CoffeeScript.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your CoffeeScript, it is very important. Add the code, select it, and hit the `{ }` icon.

Comment: `Course.first` should be `Course.findOne`?

Comment: @Peepe L-G: this is somehow somewhere set as an equivalent to Course.findOne. That's why the console.log works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem must be in the method: upvote and there you call a function that does not exist.

Even if the method looks good try to uncomment anything but a simple console.log 'hi'. And remove uncomments line by line.

Or it might be that the minimongoid package version you are using does not have update. Try Course._collection.update(...) instead.